# Toyota Auris 1329 Petrol 2011 No Start

Tags: engine, toyota, cranks-wont-run, auris

A friend has a Toyota Auris, he messaged me that it won't start and if I can come help jump start it. He drove it few days prior no issues and yesterday it just wouldn't fire up.

Got there, used a battery check tool and it said "Battery OK Battery Low" so didn't think much of it. Connected jump leads let it charge up etc. Still would not start at all.

He then mentioned he had to top up his oil last month about 2L worth which I then thought that is extremely odd for it to burn that much, personally suspected a leak. Checked his oil was bone dry. So I went to get oil and topped it up.

Even swapped batteries with my one still nothing, his battery is fine as was able to start my car with it and after running it for a bit also checked, good level on the tool.

Is his engine likely totalled? Allegedly these cars are known to have oil issues/burning etc high amounts.

When trying to start it, when it turns over nothing sounds out of ordinary, no noises/grinding or whatnot, pumping the accelerator ever so slightly get a small rev rise and it sounds as if it's about to fire up but nothing.

Is there anything else that can be checked/tried without having to pay for a diagnosis? As if engine is likely totalled he doesn't want to waste money for a diagnosis to find that out as he will just scrap it.

Thanks.

Comment: Remove spark plugs after several failed starting attempts and examine them for raw fuel. If you can, check for spark. If fuel and spark are good, squirt some oil into each cylinder and spin the starter briefly to distribute oil around piston rings, replace spark plugs and try starting again. Oil can help with compression to allow starting.

Comment: @FDryer Removed the spark plugs, could smell petrol on them, cleaned them up, dropped a bit of oil into the cylinders but nothing. I checked spark on all 4 plugs and has spark. Cylinder holes visually looked pretty clean. Not sure what's next if anything.

Comment: Electronic fuel injection;, hold gas pedal down to floor during starting. Some EFI systems disables injector operation under the presumption of a flooded engine by describing this as 'clear flood mode' when several starting attempts of a cold engine continually injects a rich fuel mixture, shorting the high voltage spark resulting in flooding the engine. GM describes this in owner's manuals to depress the gas pedal to the floor for subsequent starts to shut off injectors as excess fuel is blown out until spark ignites remaining fuel. If this doesn't work, there may be mechanical timing issues.